# pyspark dataframe, groupby and compute variance of a column

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to groupby a pyspark dataframe and compute the variance of a specific column. For the average this is quite easy and can be done like this

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as func
AVERAGES=df.groupby('country').agg(func.avg('clicks').alias('avg_clicks')).collect()
```

however for the variance there seem not to be any aggregation function in the function sub-module (I am also wondering why since this is quite a common operation)

Comment: I don't see it either.  You can probably use one of the two classical formulas for [variance,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance) either directly or as a udf.  All these need are the mean and square operations. They give you a mean operation, so you need to be able to square, for example you could use `func.pow('clicks',2)` to get clicks^2.

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is convert the dataframe to an RDD object and then use the provided variance function for RDDs.

```
df1 = df.groupby('country').agg(func.avg('clicks').alias('avg_clicks'))
rdd = df1.rdd
rdd.variance()
```

Answer (score 2):

As standard deviation is square root of variance a pure PySpark dataframe solution is :

```
df = sc.parallelize(((.1, 2.0), (.3, .2))).toDF()
df.show()
varianceDF = df.select(stddev('_1') * stddev('_1'))
varianceDF.show()
```